# MongoDB: projection to match multiple

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I am having a bit of trouble here. So I want to show a user's profile. The user belongs to groups. The logged in user can see details of any groups they have in common. Here is some example data

```
{
  _id: "1234",
  battletag: "Fake#1234",
  guilds: [{
    name: "Lok'Narosh!",
    rank: 4,
    roles: ['casual']
  }, {
    name: "Warlords of Draenor",
    rank: 2,
    roles: ['PvP', 'raider']
  }, {
    name: "Lok'Tar Ogar!",
    rank: 3,
    roles: ['raider']
  }],
}
```

I can get the current user's groups and reduce it to `['Lok'Narosh!', 'Warlords of Draenor']`, meaning that `Lok'tar Ogar` should be omitted from the results.

The main problem I am coming across is that most operations I know only return the *first* result. For example, with [$elemMatch](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/):

> The $elemMatch operator limits the contents of an  field from the query results to contain only the **first** element matching the $elemMatch condition.

Is there a way that I can filter this list to contain *all* matching elements against a list of elements?

Comment: Client side or server side? If the latter then you'll probably need to use the aggregation framework.

Answer (score 0):

You can use aggregate:

1. $unwind operator to deconstruct 'guilds' field.
2. Apply criteria with $match
3. Reconstruct array.

   db.getCollection('yourColl').aggregate({$unwind:"$guilds"},{$match:{"guilds.rank":{$gte:2.0}}},{$group:{ "_id":"$_id", "battletag":{$first:"$battletag"},"guilds":{$addToSet:"$guilds"}}})